# Windows Phone 8 application terminates on back navigation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have created WP8 application there are three pages when I navigate to the third page and then come back to Home page application just terminates with No error, The debugger stills runs in Visual Studio only Output windows shows following log:
Can anyone tell me what is happening.

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{AFD7ACFA-47D3-4AFF-A2C7-A3129A7CCF3B}\Install\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.IO.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Collections.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{AFD7ACFA-47D3-4AFF-A2C7-A3129A7CCF3B}\Install\Posh.Mako.Proxy.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{AFD7ACFA-47D3-4AFF-A2C7-A3129A7CCF3B}\Install\System.Net.Http.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{AFD7ACFA-47D3-4AFF-A2C7-A3129A7CCF3B}\Install\System.Net.Http.Primitives.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{AFD7ACFA-47D3-4AFF-A2C7-A3129A7CCF3B}\Install\microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Extensions.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Globalization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[2444] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220978 (0x8004020e).
```

Comment: see...if your application is crashed means there is any exception has been occured  so first you should check for exception ....To check exception type you should put a break point on unhandeled exception event in app.cs file

Comment: Go to Debug -> Exceptions and mark the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkboxes, and then run your application again

Comment: You may have clicked "back" once too often. The "last" GoBack will always terminate your application. Unfortunately Windows keeps all back button clicks until they are realized, even though the pages have not been loaded. That means if you are on the third page and press back quickly three times, it will open the second, the first and then terminate.